# how can i put rss feed link on my website?

Tags: php, xml, rss

i wanted to put an rss feed for a web app im creating in php,
so basically w they can subscribe to a part of a website using google reader or feedburner etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use [zend_feed_writer](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.feed.writer.html) class to generate feeds.

Answer (score 0):

Put this in the `<head>` for your homepage.

```
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="whatever" href="http://path/to/your/feed" />
```

Comment: whats the path to my feed, remeber this is user generetd content by the users of the system?

Comment: I can't possibly know that. My understanding was that you already had the feed created and that you simply wanted to know the HTML for advertising it.